Best practice: How to correctly size the delimiters/fences of the following examples?
I want to correctly set the size of the delimiters of these three equations:
\Prob{C = c}\qquad(\sum_{i = 1}^{m}x_{i})\qquad( 1 - \frac{\xi\hat{t}}{T_{L}})

Suppose, that they must be typed in the same document so they are must be consistent!
My attempt
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif}[
    Extension       = .ttf ,
    BoldFont        = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Italic ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}[
    Extension       = .ttf ,
    BoldFont        = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Oblique ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldOblique ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono}[
    Extension       = .ttf ,
    BoldFont        = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Oblique ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldOblique ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]
\setmathfont{texgyredejavu-math}[
    Extension       = .otf ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]

\newcommand\given{}
\newcommand{\blank}{\;{\cdot}\;}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Prob[1]{\operatorname{Pr}}(){}{%
\renewcommand\given{\nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}
\ifblank{#1}{\blank}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\Prob{C = c}
\qquad
\biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^{m}x_{i}\biggr)
\qquad
\biggl(1 - \frac{\xi\hat{t}}{T_{\kern-2pt L}}\biggr)
\qquad
\operatorname{E}\mathopen[(X_{t+\tau} - \mu)\mathclose] % edit (see also below)
\end{equation*}

Very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line.
This inline equation is correctly typed: \(( 2\sigma_{u}^2) /T_{\kern-2pt L}\)?

\end{document}

compiled with
latexmk --halt-on-error --file-line-error -lualatex ./foo.tex

Some considerations

IMO, the first equation is correctly typed without using the starred version or \big, \bigg, \Big or \Bigg as option. Anyway I noticed that C is a bit taller than fences. For this reason I prefer to ask.
I chose to use \biggl and \biggl in the second example as suggested on AMS Style Guide
In the last equation I followed the above guide and Mathematics
into Type. Indeed, L is not encompassed by fences. Anyway, the stacked fraction is not completely encompassed by fences: \xi is bit taller than fences like C in the first equation. Is it acceptable?

Edit

IMO, the fourth example is correctly typed at least the most inner equation. But I noticed Expect operator is not vertically centered compared to the two fences (or vice versa). IMO, this glitch can be ignored but I'm not sure. I mean the culprit is how the font built. As @egreg pointed out in its answer I also tried Latin Modern: glyphs are more centered.


Please tell us how you've defined the expectations operator.

@Mico Thank you for your answer and interest for this edit! Anyway in the previous edit I updated my MWE. Simply: \operatorname{E}. To sum up IMO there are three solution (a) do nothing, (b) change font (it's a pity!) and (c) shift/move down/up some glyphs.Do I miss some solutions? (Probably!)

Please see the addendum I posted. I find that the math font places the square brackets (and, for that matter, the round parentheses too) unusually low.

Experimenting is the only way out. Let me present an experiment:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\iftrue % change to \iffalse to use Latin Modern

\linespread{1.1}

\setmainfont{DejaVuSerif}[
    Extension       = .ttf ,
    BoldFont        = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Italic ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldItalic ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]
\setsansfont{DejaVuSans}[
    Extension       = .ttf ,
    BoldFont        = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Oblique ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldOblique ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]
\setmonofont{DejaVuSansMono}[
    Extension       = .ttf ,
    BoldFont        = *-Bold ,
    ItalicFont      = *-Oblique ,
    BoldItalicFont  = *-BoldOblique ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]
\setmathfont{texgyredejavu-math}[
    Extension       = .otf ,
    UprightFont     = * ,
]

\fi % end of conditional code

\newcommand\given{}
\newcommand{\blank}{\;{\cdot}\;}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterXPP\Prob[1]{\operatorname{Pr}}(){}{%
\renewcommand\given{%
  \nonscript\:\delimsize\vert\nonscript\:\mathopen{}}%
  \ifblank{#1}{\blank}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Prob{C = c}
\qquad
\biggl(\,\sum_{i = 1}^{m}x_{i}\biggr)
\qquad
\biggl( 1 - \frac{\xi\hat{t}}{T_{\kern-2pt L}}\biggr)
\\
\Prob{C = c}
\qquad
\Biggl(\,\sum_{i = 1}^{m}x_{i}\Biggr)
\qquad
\Biggl( 1 - \frac{\xi\hat{t}}{T_{\kern-2pt L}}\Biggr)
\\
\Prob{C = c}
\qquad
\left(\,\sum_{i = 1}^{m}x_{i}\right)
\qquad
\left( 1 - \frac{\xi\hat{t}}{T_{\kern-2pt L}}\right)
\end{gather*}

Very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line.
This inline equation is correctly typed: \(( 2\sigma_{u}^2) /T_{\kern-2pt L}\)?

\end{document}


You can see \, before each summation symbol in order to avoid clashes. Also \linespread{1.1} avoids lines being too tight (alternatively, scale the fonts down a bit).
Repeat the experiment with Latin Modern Math (by changing \iftrue into \iffalse):

What can we see? With DejaVu, \Bigg size seems good both for summations and fractions, but \bigg size isn't bad either. With Latin Modern \Bigg is definitely excessive.
Sorry, but there's no hard and fast rule: the design of the fonts is a decisive factor.

Grazie Enrico della risposta! I added a little edit to my question. During document revision I removed a lot \mleft and \mright to replace with more appropriate size. I encountered the glitch above. Since you showed me that "the design of the fonts is a decisive factor" I would want to know: How do you treat this case? Changing font is acceptable answer. Sorry, I duplicated this comment.

@miticollo I've experimented different math fonts and each one requires particular attention to the details. I'm afraid there's no general rule.

I know this. But with your experience what would you suggest for this case (see edit above in my question)? Here I found three possible solutions for me (I'm newbie with math typography).

@miticollo Sorry, but my impression is that the math font isn't really properly designed.

It is not a truism that the fences must be tall and deep enough to fully enclose their arguments. Fine typography, including fine math typography, is characterized by visual balance: All elements are easily and equally visible, and no one element dominates others. Fences that fully enclose their argument tend to be visually dominant, i.e., they tend to be too large and thereby fail the visual-balance criterion.
I'd say all three of your display-style math mode equations are ok; in particular, the \bigg fence sizes in the second and third expression are fine (and typographically correct). Do note that the third equation could (should?) easily be rewritten using inline-fraction notation instead of with \frac; cf. the fourth equation.
The inline equation also looks fine, except that it features an unnecessary pair of parentheses.
The Dejavu Serif math font is characterized, among other things, but fairly short fences/delimiters. That clearly reflects a conscious choice of the font designer. If you can't stand this design choice, maybe consider using a different math font altogether?

% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math} % 'unicode-math' loads 'amsmath' automatically
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Dejavu Math}

\DeclareMathOperator\Prob{Pr}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\Prob(C = c)
\qquad
\biggl(\sum_{i = 1}^{m} x_{i} \biggr)
\qquad
\biggl( 1 - \frac{\xi\hat{t}}{T_{\mkern-6mu L}} \biggr)
\quad
( 1 - \xi\hat{t}/T_{\mkern-6mu L} )
\end{equation*}

An inline equation: \( 2\sigma_{\! u}^2 /T_{\mkern-6mu L}\)

\end{document}


Addendum to discuss the OP's additional equation: I suppose I'd run \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} in the preamble and re-write the equation as \E[X_{t+\tau} - \mu] -- no need for both square brackets and round parentheses. Anyway, the issue is not that E is placed too high; the issue is, rather, that the square brackets are placed unusually low. Another reason to maybe reassess the suitability of this math font?
